# Linux: exit forked child process when parent exits

Tags: c, linux, fork

I'm writing a program in C. The program does `fork()` once when it starts. What's the best way to let child process die on its own when the parent process exits (without parent killing child process explicitly)?

For example, if I send a SIGTERM to the parent process, the child doesn't exit.

Comment: @CarlNorum no C answer..

Comment: The question says "without parent killing child process explicitly".

Comment: the child could call _Exit the parent doesn't have to

Comment: Read: [Orphan process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphan_process) and its drop backs

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a signal handler, and send a signal to the child process from the parent when the parent reaches the end of its execution. The `fork` function returns the process id of the child to the parent, so this can be supplied to the `kill` function. You can pass it `SIGINT` or `SIGTERM` or the signal of your choosing.

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
    pid_t id = 0;
    id = fork();
    if( id == 0 ) {
            /*child code*/
    } else if( id == -1 ) {
            printf( "Error forking." );
    } else {
            /*parent code*/
            kill( id, SIGINT );
    }
    return 0;
```

}